# Using the "sample" function in r to randomly select rows from a a data frame into a new dataframe, while also storing non-sampled rows

Tags: r

My objective for a school project is to randomly select a proportion of a dataset into a new subset, while also storing the non-sampled observations in another data frame using the "sample" function in base R.

Using the following code below yields a random sample of my made up data frame.

```
DATA <- data.frame(x=c(3, 5, 6, 6, 8, 12, 14),
                 y=c(12, 6, 4, 23, 25, 8, 9),
                  z=c(2, 7, 8, 8, 15, 17, 29))



sample <- DATA[sample(1:nrow(DATA), floor(nrow(DATA)*0.7), replace = FALSE),]
```

However, i run into trouble when i want to extract the non-sampled observations aswell, which is where i run into troubles. Most resources i've come across suggest something like the  code below,

```
training <- DATA[sample,]
testing <- DATA[-sample,]
```

but that option yields the error message

> Error in xj[i] : invalid subscript type 'list'

Any help to solve the situation would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, `sample` is a dataframe. You need `sample` to be index  to make `DATA[sample,]` and `DATA[-sample,]` work.

```
sample <- sample(nrow(DATA), floor(nrow(DATA)*0.7))

training <- DATA[sample,]
testing <- DATA[-sample,]
```

Simplified the `sample(..)` call.

- `sample(1:nrow(DATA), ..)` is same as `sample(nrow(DATA), ..)`
- By default `replace` is `FALSE` in `sample` so no need to explicitly mention it.